# what will happen if we create more than 2^31 distinct objects?

Tags: java, hashcode

In java programming language we know the return type of hashcode method is int. So there can't be more than 2^31 distinct objects. Is it true? If yes then what will happen if we create more than 2^31 distinct objects?

Comment: Just try and find out what happens?

Comment: Two different objects can have the same hashcode (that's called hash collision)

Comment: This seems to be a question about some specific hashcode implementation in some specific language (possibly on a particular platform where `int` has only 2^31 possible values). But you haven't told us which.

Comment: Sorry to mention I am asking about java language

Answer (score 1):

You will have duplicate hashcodes very soon and this is not a problem. There`s a good article about hash code that also covers hash code duplicates.

For the direct answer: you don`t have to fake it, it just happens!
"..the number of possible distinct objects is usually bigger than the number of possible hash codes (2^32)."

For clarification:

"A collision is nothing critical, it just means that there is more than one object in a single bucket, so a HashMap lookup has to look again to find the right object. A lot of collisions will degrade the performance of a system, but they won’t lead to incorrect results."

Source: [The 3 things you should know about hashCode()](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/)

Answer (score 0):

It is totally ok for several objects to have the same hashcode. So many objects will not cause any troubles (there).

Just try it out, and create a class, that always returns "42" as hashcode. As long as you have a reasonably `equals` method, storing those objects in a `HashMap` will work fine.

But in terms of **performance**, it is advisable to generate wide spread hashcodes.